Angular - Creates two instances of singleton service when using external library
I am working in a monorepo with NX as tool for working with common component class.
I have a component in my library that looks something like this:
export class MyCommonComponent {
  constructor(private storageService: StorageService){}
}

StorageService is an abstract that I want to implement in the apps. Looks something like this:
export abstract class StorageService {
  abstract functionA(): void;
}

In my project I have 4 different apps that will have their own implementation of StorageService.
So in application A, I created a new service with as:
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class ApplicationAStorageImplementation implements StorageService {
  functionA(): void {.....}
}

Since my component is not aware of the implementation, I must use some provider for DI I suppose.
So in my app.module.ts I then have:
providers: [
    {
      provide: StorageService,
      useClass: ApplicationAStorageImplementation
    },
]

However, now it creates two instances of StorageService, and I don't want this since StorageService is supposed to work as a singleton.
What am I doing wrong?
It creates one instance when I load my application because one of my components uses StorageService. Then it creates a new instance when MyCommonComponent is being created.

Would recommend adding the Nx tag for attention. But question for you, are you using Nx as an MFE system with Module Federation or are you just using it as a monorepo container?

Just as monorepo container for now! @MichaelZiluck

Using useExisting instead of useClass solved my issue here. Now I don't have two instances of my services.
